# Add commas between allowed file extensions

Tags: files

I need to restrict the user to upload only the file extensions that i mentioned in the Allowed file extensions filed. It works properly. But in front-end, i need to add a comma separator for this format.

Actual - Allowed file types: ai aif avi bmp csv doc docx eps fla flv gif img.

Expected - Allowed file types: ai, aif, avi, bmp, csv, doc, docx, eps, fla, flv, gif, img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely allowed to separate file types by comma in the admin are

[image]

For user area, find the ID of the form (you can find this in the firebug) then

```
function YourTheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
      if($form_id == "TheFormID"){
            kpr($form);  
      }
}
```

In this way you can find the form elements. get the Key of image field in the form array, if it is `image` then write

```
function YourTheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
      if($form_id == "TheFormID"){
            $form['image']['#description'] = t('File types are comma separated')
      }
}
```

This is the general idea but a few modification might be needed

Comment: This is back-end (admin area). I need to add comma in front-end (where the user uploads their files).

Comment: I need to add comma separation here.  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/B41dP.png

Comment: My code does this, it finds the ID of the form and alters the `description`

Answer (score 1):

I used theme_file_upload_help hook.

```
 function bartik_file_upload_help($variables) {

 $description = $variables ['description'];

 $upload_validators = $variables ['upload_validators'];

 $descriptions = array();

  if (strlen($description)) {

     $descriptions [] = $description;
    }

  if (isset($upload_validators ['file_validate_size'])) {

     $descriptions [] = t('Files must be less than !size.', array('!size' => '<strong>' . format_size($upload_validators ['file_validate_size'][0]) . '</strong>'));

 }

 $a = explode(" ", $upload_validators ['file_validate_extensions'][0] );
  if (isset($upload_validators ['file_validate_extensions'])) {

$descriptions [] = t('Allowed file types: !extensions.', array('!extensions' => '<strong>' . check_plain(implode(", ", $a)) . '</strong>'));

 }

return implode('<br />', $descriptions);

}
```